# TestNG plugin install error

Tags: eclipse, testng

I am trying to install TestNG plugin in eclipse it is not getting installed and iam getting the below error message

> Communication with repository at htt://beust.com/eclipse/ failed.
>   Org.eclipse.equinoxp2.core.ProvisionException

Comment: Which Os and eclipse version you are using?

Comment: Did you miss a 'p' in http?

Comment: beust.com/eclipse this is the site url i am using for installing testng plug -ins in windows 7 Ultimate operating system